# set up a FTP server with a GUI

Tags: ftp

I want to set up a FTP server (which I can access outside of my home network) and I have the following criterias:

1. I want to set up access for a specific user and block access to everyone else - preferably if I can give access by entering the person's IP-address beforehand.
2. I want to do the setup preferably through a graphic user interface, and not editing a bunch of text files or the likes.

**Is there an Ubuntu software with graphical interface where I can setup the server settings with the above criterias met?** Like you can with a bunch of other programs nowadays in Ubuntu LTS (I have OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Imagine Filzezilla server on Windows for example; that's what I want/prefer.

.....................

I also have 2 follow-up questions related to FTP server guides:

1. I've also tried following this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/servergu...-configuration
   Simple. I entered the command sudo apt install vsftpd so I guess that vsftpd is installed, but now what? Where and how do I access it so I can set up settings and password?
2. I have found this comperehensive guide but I want to make sure it is solid, and not deceiving me to do something I don't understand: https://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-an-FTP-Server-in-Ubuntu-Linux

Do I get the experts' approval to follow this guide?

Comment: FTP GUI is a feature of the FTP client, not the server. An Ubuntu desktop can function as an GUI FTP Client for any FTP server - the client functionality is already baked into Nautilus.

Comment: You cannot "set up a FTP server (which I can access outside of my home network)". You may setup `vsftpd` , read `man vsftpd` and `vsftpd.conf` and the files in `/usr/share/doc/vsftpd/` to serve files via FTP on a _system_ accessible from outside. This is more dangerous than it looks.

Comment: You do NOT get this expert's approval to blindly follow ANY set of instructions. You MUST understand what they're telling you to do and how that will affect your system.